# Should component re-render after form submit and action dispatches?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component, which has a form, when a user clicks the submit button and after the validation is successful, an action dispatches (this all happens within the submit event).

Should the component re-render after the action dispatches?

Currently, I don't see this happening, what could be the reason?
Let me add, what's happening here.
1) form is submitted;
2) the validation is run;
3) the action dispatches (it sends the data to backend to save it into the database);

In the reducer, I have defined:

```
    const messages = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_MESSAGE_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, message: action.message, error: null, isMessageLoading: false };
        case ADD_MESSAGE_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, message: null, error: action.error, isMessageLoading: false };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

And in the console log, I can clearly see that the state has changed.
But no re-render occurs at this stage.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        message: state.messages.message,
        isMessageLoading: state.messages.isMessageLoading
    }
};
```

So when the action dispatches, the props gets updated.

This is the code of an action

```
    export const addMessage = (message) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: ADD_MESSAGE });
        return fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/contacts`, {
            credentials: 'include',
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(message),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then((data) => {
            dispatch(addMessageSuccess(data));
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(`An error occurred while adding contact message: ${error}`);
            dispatch(addMessageFailure(error));
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: The component will usually only rerender if the props or state have changed.  If submitting the form doesn't do either of these things then I would not expect it to.  Post some code if you want more detailed answers.

Comment: If the state doesn't change then the component won't re-render

Comment: The dispatched action changes the state, I can clearly see it in the console log.

Comment: how are you confirming that the component is not re-rendering?

Comment: Then please provide your code

Comment: I added console.log("Re-render") in the render part of the component.

Comment: If the form component is connected to the store (which I assume it is if it dispatching actions) then one of the props has to change (i.e. the values in `mapStateToProps`) for the component to rerender.

Comment: I have added the mapStateToProps to the post. It does not help.

Answer (score 3):

Connected components will re-render if the state changes (and the changed state is being selected in `mapStateToProps`)

In your case, both `message` or `isMessageLoading` can trigger the update.

Note that if the message is a string and you dispatch the actions that contain the same message string, **your component will not re-render**. For example, the current `message` state is `success`, and you dispatch another action which also contains `message: success`:

```
{
  type: ADD_MESSAGE_SUCCESS,
  message: 'success'
}
```

Then your component won't update. That's because there are some optimization in React-Redux's `connect`

A simple example here: https://jsfiddle.net/njk5teoh/ (I also add `error` to the component), you can click the submit button several times and see the console log.

If this doesn't solve your problem, you may need to provide a reproducible jsfiddle/codepen or repo.

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation, I was able to reproduce the same behavior when there is no REST operations in the dispatch action. But in my case I have a save action, which save data to the database and in this case, it does not work.

Comment: I have added the action code, with this action, I never get the re-render. From my understanding, the fetch is async, so the handleSubmit is finished when the updated state is makes from the database.

Comment: What is the `data` of `addMessageSuccess(data)`?

Comment: You have to make sure that your state does have changes.

Comment: I will also suggest you to use redux-logger or redux-devtool so that you can see your state changes easily. If your state did change, make sure you don't have `shouldComponentUpdate` in your component

Comment: Some other possible mistakes: 1. your didn't declare or import the action types (like `ADD_MESSAGE_SUCCESS`) correctly; 2. the structure of your action object is incorrect

Comment: I have created JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/nomadus/njk5teoh/28/. It re-renders at first attempt, but the subsequent attempts does not re-render. Although it should re-render after each changes

Comment: That's what I just described in my answer. Your `state.message` is not being updated. `connect`ed components will do a shallow comparison to the prev and next state, since the `message` is always the same, your component will not re render

Comment: Also the `App` doesn't need a local state. These states are already saved in the redux store

Comment: I skipped adding message attribute in the action, now I have corrected and in JSFiddle I can see that the component re-renders. This is not happening with my local project, let me investigate what is the difference between them.

Comment: hey @CodinCat, I found what was the issue, it was my mistake, I configured the store wrong, after I made it correctly, now I am seeing the component re-render. I shall accept your answer, as it helped me to analyse once more my code.